# How can I stop iPhone sync'ing "Genius Data"?

Tags: ios, music.app

Every time I sync my iPhone with my desktop computer, it takes a long time because it insists on sync'ing nearly 5000 items of "Genius Data":

[image]

*I don't use Genius **at all***, and would be happy if the sync process would stop wasting my time with this step. Yet, I cannot find a way to turn it off.

**How can I make the synchronization process ignore or skip over this "Genius" data**, but synchronize everything else?

I'm running macOS 10.15.7 and the latest version of iOS.

Comment: Are you OK letting play counts on the phone not update the main music library? Hopefully we don’t need to catalog all the settings possible for your version of the music player on both your computer and device. https://support.apple.com/guide/music/general-preferences-mus4130f48/mac

Comment: iTunes > File > Library > Turn off Genius [can't check newer 'Music' app right now]

Comment: @bmike Yes, thanks, that would be fine – updating the play counts is not very important (to me, anyway).

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, in my copy of the Music app on maOS Catalina, there is no Turn off Genius in that menu. There is only "Update Genius".

Comment: Hmmm. just looked in Monterey [which I couldn't get to earlier] - still right there, same place as it was in Mojave [iTunes].

Comment: @Tetsujin I can absolutely guarantee you that it is **not** in the menus on my copy. Perhaps there are some additional conditions that change the available options.

Comment: https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/us/genius.html mentions a 'Store' menu… I don't have one of those.